# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.swing.UIManager

Tags: java, swing, noclassdeffounderror, uimanager

**I have meet this error,does anyone know why is it?  Java Version: 1.6.0_16**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.swing.UIManager
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:191)
    at ilog.views.chart.IlvChart.updateUI(Unknown Source)
```

**and it print another error that:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: shell32.dll: Cannot load shell32.dll from system directories.
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.init(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.<init>(WDesktopProperties.java:66)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyInitWProps(WToolkit.java:817)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(WToolkit.java:807)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1759)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Toolkit.java:1740)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.<clinit>(UIManager.java:357)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(LookAndFeel.java:191)
    at ilog.views.chart.IlvChart.updateUI(Unknown Source)
```

**does them have any relations indeep?**

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running on Windows, shell32.dll should be in your system32 folder, e.g. `c:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll`.

It seems unlikely that you'd be able to run Windows without it... perhaps your JDK/JRE has become corrupt somehow? Maybe a registry entry gone astray? Possibly worth reinstalling just the JDK/JRE - and if you're on a 64-bit machine, make sure you install a 64-bit version. While I'd expect the 32-bit version to work too (like any other 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows) it's just about conceivable that it would lead to this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled my JDK, and then ran into this error while trying to use the WindowBuilder Editor in Eclipse.

I fixed the problem by restarting Eclipse.